# Is $\mathscr{B}$ a filter on $X$, or only a filter base

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $X_1$ be a nonempty set, $\mathscr{B}_1$ a filter on $X_1$, $X_2$ a nonempty set, $\mathscr{B}_2$ a filter on $X_2$; now we define $X=X_1\times X_2$ and

$$\mathscr{B}=\{B_1\times B_2:B_1 \in \mathscr{B}_1\text{ and }B_2 \in \mathscr{B}_2\}\;.$$

The answer is

Is $\mathscr{B}$ a filter on $X$, or is $\mathscr{B}$ just a base for a filter on $X$?

I think $\mathscr{B}$ is a filter on $X$, but is there anyone here whocan help me?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $B_1\in\mathscr{B}_1$ and $B_2\in\mathscr{B}_2$, and that $x_1\in X_1\setminus B_1$ and $x_2\in X_2\setminus B_2$.

- Is $(B_1\times B_2)\cup\{\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\}$ in the filter generated by $\mathscr{B}\,$?
- Is $(B_1\times B_2)\cup\{\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\}$ in $\mathscr{B}\,$?

A schematic picture can help:

[image]

The horizontal line is $X_1$; the vertical line is $X_2$, and the large rectangle is $X_1\times X_2$. The red box is $B_1\times B_2$, and the point above and to its right is $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$, so the red line and dot at the bottom are $B_1$ and $x_1$, and the red line and dot at the left are $B_2$ and $x_2$.